# Question about Determining Eigenvectors Without Using Row Echelon Form

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there anyway of determining nontrivial (nonzero) components for Eigenvectors after computing a particular Eigenvalue from the characteristic equation besides using row reduction and iterative means? The part where you substitute a particular λ from the characteristic equation back into the (A-λI)x=0 and solve for the Eigenvalues just seems tedious by using row reduction form to solve for the Eigenvectors. I know it has a determinant of zero for the A-λI matrix and the b vector is 0, so I was curious if there was a way of manipulating the equation to another form to solve for these values.

Comment: Row reduction is the one direct method that we have for solving a linear system; iterative methods are the indirect ones. That's pretty much all you can do. If you're looking for a shortcut for $2 \times 2$ hand calculations, one trick is that one row will always be redundant, so you can simply ignore one of them (your choice, unless a row is zero, in which case you need to ignore that one specifically).

Comment: For example, this trick is helpful in computing the eigenvectors of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$; here the eigenvalues are $\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$, which makes row reduction messy. But by ignoring a row entirely you avoid that messy arithmetic.

Comment: Ok. That is interesting for a 2x2 matrix. Thanks.

Comment: That trick usually works for larger matrices as well, but it's less reliable. For instance in a 3x3 case, usually a 3x3 non-invertible matrix gets that way because one row is a combination of both of the other rows. But occasionally it could happen that it is actually just a multiple of *one* of the other rows. (Example: $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$.) In this case you cannot ignore the third row; by doing so you could accidentally say that there are two linearly independent eigenvectors for an eigenvalue which actually only has one.

Comment: In these larger cases, even though the trick usually does work, checking that it does quickly starts to be more work than just doing the row reduction.